# How to add nested message into already created message ? (in Scala)

Tags: scala, protocol-buffers, scalapb

After adding nested message i recieve nested messages from main message and got nothing.

You can see it in logs: 1 and 2. Size of List 0 !

Any ideas?

```
message PacketPlayers
{
    repeated PacketPlayer players = 1;
}
```

[image]

Comment: is your PacketPlayers.players a mutable or an immutable List?

Comment: @Samar it's immutable seq by default, can't change

Comment: Is PacketPlayers.players a val or a var, can you show the code for your PacketPlayers class? Also, its better if you paste your code instead of pasting png's. You will get more responses.

Comment: @Samar val or var doesn't matter because class cointains immutable collection. Code for PacketPlayer is autogenerated from Proto3. Nothing interesting there for humans. I found solution and it was very obvious :( Rearranged code, made a mutable collection with nested messages and sent it(collection) to constructor. Thanks for answering anyway! :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ScalaPB case classes are immutable. In your example, `addPlayers` would not modify the instance it's called on, but return a new instance of `PacketPlayer` that has the additional players.

It is possible to avoid mutable arrays and vars in constructing the new object. For example:

```
val players = onlinePlayers.keySet.map(makePacketPlayer)
val packetPlayers = PacketPlayers().withPlayers(players)
```